# Онлайн ACM подобные тестирующие системы

Tags: linux, память, время, memory

Я прочитал данную [статью](http://www.quora.com/What-is-the-simplest-and-most-accurate-way-to-measure-the-memory-used-by-a-program-in-a-programming-contest-environment) про лимиты памяти, и написал некий код, который вычисляет те или иные значения памяти и времени.

1. Как я понял, функция `clock()` измеряет время процессора, которое сильно отличается от того, что выводит мне команда `time` в шелле. Каким образом в тестирующих системах это отслеживается?
2. Есть куча разных полей типа:

   ```
   VmPeak:    11884 kB
   VmSize:    11884 kB
   VmLck:         0 kB
   VmHWM:      1108 kB
   VmRSS:      1108 kB
   VmData:      272 kB
   VmStk:        88 kB
   VmExe:        16 kB
   VmLib:      3244 kB
   VmPTE:        48 kB
   VmSwap:        0 kB
   ```

   Как именно ограничивают ресурсы в тестирующих системах?
   Вариант с `ps aux` совсем не годен для коротко работающих программ.

Comment: конкретизируйте, пожалуйста, о каких именно «тестирующих системах» речь.

Comment: ACM подобных конечно же, где же ещё применяется это?)

Comment: понятия не имею, что такое «acm-подобные тестирующие системы», но если вам доступны исходники какой-нибудь из них, вы можете посмотреть, как реализована в них интересующая вас функциональность. если исходников нет, то вопрос не по теме данного сайта: вам надо обращаться на соответствующие форумы или в службы техподдержки интересующих вас программ.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin тестирующие системы - это, например, системы для проверки заданий на олимпиадах. ТС спрашивает как сделать такое ограничение, а не как оно сделано в какой-то конкретной системе.

Comment: @PashaPash, вероятно, я не понял смысла, вложенного автором в вопросы *Каким образом в тестирующих системах это отслеживается?* и *Какие именно ограничивают ресурсы в тестирующих системах?* мне показалось, что они как раз об **уже существующих** системах, а не о той, которую автор, вероятно, хочет написать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обычно измеряется процессорное время. Это то, что `time` выводит как `user`.

По памяти - вам нужен показатель VmSize. Или VmPeak - это пиковое значение VmSize.
Если хотите считать совсем честно - то надо отнять от него data/stack/exe/lib - это не "использование памяти" в смысле явного выделения в коде.

Данные по памяти нельзя определить после завершения процесса, так что единственный вариант - достаточно часто опрашивать данные в фоне. Значение VmPeak за долю секунды до завершения кода будет практически актуальным как "максимум использованной памяти". И заодно следить за превышением выделенного времени выполнения.

Писать свою систему с нуля достаточно тяжело. Посмотрите исходники существующих систем, например [ejudge](https://github.com/blackav/ejudge/blob/master/unix/ej_process.c).

Comment: Вообще-то, обычно на олимпиадах измеряется как раз процессорное время - чтобы уменьшить влияние на результат всяких параллельных процессов (не каждая олимпиада может позволить себе выделенный сервер-проверяльщик). Реальное время выполнения тоже ограничивается - но там ограничение ставится, к примеру, в два раза больше чем ограничение по процессорному времени.

Comment: @PavelMayorov давно участвовал в олимпиадах, могу обмануть. Знаю только что прибивают процесс обычно по реальному времени выполнения. Поэтому и дал ссылку на исходники eJudge.

Comment: Печально известный вердикт TL (Time-Limit Excedeed) - это именно превышение лимита процессорного времени. Приведенная вами же система ejudge превышение лимита реального времени называет WT (Wall Time Limit Excedeed), о чем можно узнать из ее вики. Другие системы могут называть его RTL, RL или DE (Deadlock).

Comment: Вообще, такая ошибка, как превышение лимита реального времени, может возникнуть только в двух случаях: 1. слишком много дисковых операций, 2. программа ожидает клавиатурного ввода :)

Comment: @PavelMayorov ок, спасибо, исправил. в мои времена тестирующие системы были совсем не те, что сейчас ) и на гитхаб их никто не выкладывал. )

Comment: Тогда вторая поправка: процессорное время режима ядра обычно не учитывается. Учитывается только то время, которое работает именно программа участника. То самое, которое `time` выводит как `user`

Comment: @PashaPash большое спасибо. Как раз и заметил что реальная секунда в процессоре где то пол секунды. т.е. вполне адекватно будет его вырубать по timeout  удвоенным временем.

Comment: @PavelMayorov большое спасибо

Comment: Али, это очень странно. Соотношение реальных секунд к процессорным очень сильно зависит от задачи. Но для вычислительных задач (а олимпиадные задачи обычно такие и есть) - соотношение должно быть 1:1.

Comment: Есть ещё одна проблема. Когда я создаю массив, скажем на 1000000 элементов, то тот while что много раз считывает его показывает то же VmPeak и Size что и без массива. Т.е. его создание никак не влияет на всё это дело. Почему же это так?

Comment: @АлиВелиев потому что вы не обращаетесь к элементам массива. И потому что 1000000 - это мало. Добавьте нулей :)

Comment: Но в том же e-olimp и acm-timus создав массив и заполнив его числами разница в программах будет где-то на 3 мегабайта (у них самих тоже варьируется, но в среднем это такое значение)

Answer (score 1):

ограничить время выполнения какой-нибудь программы можно, например, так:

```
$ программа & sleep 0.5; kill $! &>/dev/null && \
    echo "программа не уложилась в пол-секунды".
```

пример — «уложилась»:

```
$ sleep 0.4 & sleep 0.5; kill $! &>/dev/null && \
    echo "программа не уложилась в пол-секунды"
[1] 31136
[1]+  Done                    sleep 0.4
```

пример — «не уложилась»:

```
$ sleep 0.6 & sleep 0.5; kill $! &>/dev/null && \
    echo "программа не уложилась в пол-секунды"
[1] 31139
программа не уложилась в пол-секунды
[1]+  Terminated              sleep 0.6
```